Integrals of inverse functions
This final question on a calc1 final is giving me problems and I feel like I've tried everything I've learnt so far. I tried drawing diagrams and looking at it geometrically, tried substitution in the second integral, differentiated both sides with respect to $t$ to show the left side grows faster for all rates of change of $a$ and $b$, but none of it worked all the way to an answer. Would appreciate some help or at least a hint.


let $f(x)$ be an increasing real-valued function defined for $x\geq0$,for which $f(0)=0.$ Let its inverse be $f^{-1}(x).$ Given $a$ and $b$ in the domains of $f$ and $f^{-1}$, respectively, show that:
$$\int_0^af(x)dx+\int_0^bf^{-1}(x)dx\geq ab$$



Did you draw a picture?

Yeah, but I wasn't sure where to go from there. The inequality makes sense intuitively but idk how to prove it.

I notice that the simplest example $f(x)=x$ gives you a version of the AM-GM inequality $\frac 12(a^2+b^2) \ge ab$

You're asking us to do a question on your final exam? What would your teacher say about that?!

Don't worry, just a previous exam whose answers I couldn't find online.

Well, please rephrase your question carefully. Edit your post to tell us things you've tried. Have you thought about Riemann sums? Substitution in one of the integrals?

After reading above it looks like you are asking the question of your current final exam

I'm not. This is on a 2022 UofT calc1 exam for first years. Won't say more because I don't really want to dox myself. And how would I even ask a question like this during my exam? Or why waste almost an hour of time on a single question?

Consult Wikipedia
Or, even better, just the picture from that page:


Notice that the statement is trivially true if $a$ or $b$ are zero. Now suppose $a,b>0$ and assume without loss of generality that $b \geq f(a)$. Note that if this is not true, we can rewrite this in terms of a new function $g(x) = f^{-1}(x)$ and relabel $a$ and $b$ so it is true.
Now notice that $\int_0^a f(x)~dx$ and $\int_0^{f(a)}f^{-1}(x)~dx$ represent complementary components of a rectangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,f(a))$, $(a,f(a))$, and $(a,0)$, which has area $af(a)$. We therefore have a partial result
$$
\int_0^af(x)~dx + \int_0^{f(a)}f^{-1}(x)~dx = af(a).
$$
Notice that this proves the result in the case where $f(a) = b$. Now assume that $b > f(a)$ and consider the sum in the problem:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^af(x)~dx + \int_0^{b}f^{-1}(x)~dx &= \int_0^af(x)~dx + \int_0^{f(a)}f^{-1}(x)~dx + \int_{f(a)}^{b}f^{-1}(x)~dx \\
&= af(a) + \int_{f(a)}^{b}f^{-1}(x)~dx.
\end{aligned}
$$
Now notice that $f$, and therefore $f^{-1}$, are increasing functions. Since $b > f(a)$, $f^{-1}$ is bounded from below by $f^{-1}(f(a)) = a$. We then have
$$
\int_{f(a)}^{b}f^{-1}(x)~dx \geq a(b - f(a)).
$$
Combining this with the previous result, we obtain
$$
\int_0^af(x)~dx + \int_0^{b}f^{-1}(x)~dx = af(a) + \int_{f(a)}^{b}f^{-1}(x)~dx \geq af(a) + a(b - f(a)) = ab. ~\quad\blacksquare
$$

Thanks for the help. Most of this makes sense to me except the idea that we can rewrite the assumption that b>=f(a) using the inverse of f by defining a new function. I'm not sure how we reach that conclusion. Are we just saying we can swap a and b + f and its inverse to make it true?

Suppose $b \leq f(a)$ and define $g(x) = f^{-1}(x)$. $g$ is an increasing function, so we have $g(b) \leq g(f(a)) = a$. Relabel $a$ and $b$ and we are done
